# Convert from type "any" to Object

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, angular7

I'm trying to learn Angular from a online course but the course use an older version of Angular, until now i was able to adapt to Angualar 7 but now i'm stuck in this problem:

In the component he defines a Vehicle object of type any, and set its value using an api, like this:

```
"vehicle: any = {
  features: [],
  contact: {}
};"

ngOnInit() {

      var sources =[]; //I omitted the other properties

    if(this.vehicle.id)    
      sources.push(this.vehicleService.getVehicle(this.vehicle.id));

    forkJoin(sources).subscribe(data => {
          if (this.vehicle.id)
             this.Vehicle= data[0];
});
```

API code:

```
  getMakes() {
    return this.http.get('/api/makes')
      .map(res => res.json());
  }
```

Since I'm using Angular 7 i changed the API code to this:

```
  getVehicle(id){
    return this.http.get<any>('api/vehicles/'+id);
  }
```

And it worked like a charm. But now it changed the code to use models (a copy of the models used in the api) like this:

```
    vehicle: SaveVehicle = {
    id:0,
    makeId: 0,
    modelId: 0,
    isRegistered: false,
    features: [],
    contact: {
      name: '',
      email: '',
      phone: '',
    }
  };


ngOnInit() {

    var sources =[]; //I omitted the other properties

    if(this.vehicle.id)    
      sources.push(this.vehicleService.getVehicle(this.vehicle.id));

    forkJoin(sources).subscribe(data => {

          if (this.vehicle.id)
             this.setVehicle(data[0]);
});


    private setVehicle(vehicle: Vehicle) {
        this.vehicle.id = vehicle.id;
        this.vehicle.makeId = vehicle.make.id;
        this.vehicle.modelId = vehicle.model.id;
        this.vehicle.isRegistered = vehicle.isRegistered;
        this.vehicle.contact = vehicle.contact;
        this.vehicle.features = _.pluck(vehicle.features,'id');   
      }
```

When i changed the method this line

```
this.setVehicle(data[0]);
```

throws the exception:

Argument of type 'any[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Vehicle'.
  Type 'any[]' is missing the following properties from type 'Vehicle': id, model, make, isRegistered, and 3 more.

I changed the return type of the API call to Vehicle, it does work but then i cannot use the *sources* array anymore because the other Observables in the array has different types. Should i use any as return of the api call ? Is there a way to keep the sources array while changing the return type to Vehicles ? Can i cast from "any" to Vehicle  ?

In one questio: What should i do here ?

Comment: `var sources: Vehicle[] = []`

Comment: If you want to watch an intro to Angular that is updated to Angular v7, you can watch this one, which is FREE for the month of February: https://app.pluralsight.com/library/courses/angular-2-getting-started-update

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have a Vehicle interface as follows (or similar):

```
export interface Vehicle {
  id: number;
  makeId: number;
  modelId: number;
  isRegistered: boolean;
  features: [];
  contact: {};
}
```

Change the get method as follows:

```
constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

getVehicle(id){
  return this.http.get<Vehicle>('api/vehicles/'+id);
}

getVehicles(){
  return this.http.get<Vehicle[]>('api/vehicles');
}
```

This maps the response into the shape of a single vehicle or an array of Vehicles.

Be sure to use `httpClient` (new in 4.3 ish) and not the old `http`.

Also, you should not really need code like this:

```
private setVehicle(vehicle: Vehicle) {
    this.vehicle.id = vehicle.id;
    this.vehicle.makeId = vehicle.make.id;
    this.vehicle.modelId = vehicle.model.id;
    this.vehicle.isRegistered = vehicle.isRegistered;
    this.vehicle.contact = vehicle.contact;
    this.vehicle.features = _.pluck(vehicle.features,'id');   
  }
```

Define your model so it matches the shape and names from the response.

Alternatively, map the data from one structure to the other in the `http.get`:

```
getVehicle(id): Observable<Vehicle> {
  return this.http.get<any>('api/vehicles/'+id).pipe(
    map(v => ({                       
       id: v.id,
       makeId: v.make.id,
       modelId: v.model.id,
       isRegistered: v.isRegistered,
       contract: v.contract;
       features: _.pluck(v.features,'id')
    })
  );
}
```

The above maps the incoming response (defined as type `any`) to the Vehicle as defined by the interface.

NOTE: The above mapping was NOT syntax checked!

ALSO NOTE: The parenthesis are required around the curly braces here:

```
v => ( { 
   ... 
})
```

Because otherwise the compiler thinks that we are defining a statement block instead of a returned object literal.

Comment: Thank you. I'll try to map the return of the API like you suggested. In the tutorial he uses two different interfaces for vehicle, that's why it has the SetVehicle method.